# Autofac SingleInstance Update failed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, autofac

I have following class for save and get my user's data.

```
 public class AuthenticationMethod : IAuthenticationMethod
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly IFormCustomizationsService _formCustomizationsService;
    private readonly IGridCustomizationsService _gridCustomizationsService;

    public virtual User CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ViewFormCustomizations> CurrentFormCustomizations { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ViewGridCustomizations> CurrentGridCustomizations { get; set; }

    public AuthenticationMethod(IUserService userService, IFormCustomizationsService formCustomizationsService, IGridCustomizationsService gridCustomizationsService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _gridCustomizationsService = gridCustomizationsService;
        _formCustomizationsService = formCustomizationsService;
    }

    public bool LoginCurrentUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        CurrentUser = _userService.IsAuthenticated(userName, password);
        if (CurrentUser == null || !CurrentUser.IsActive)
        {
            CurrentUser = null;
            return false;
        }

        Initialize(CurrentUser);
        return true;
    }

    public void LogoutCurrentUser()
    {
        CurrentUser = null;
        CurrentFormCustomizations = null;
        CurrentGridCustomizations = null;
    }

    public virtual void Initialize(User user)
    {
        CurrentUser = user;

        InitialFormCustomizations();
        InitialGridCustomizations();
    }

    public virtual void InitialFormCustomizations()
    {
        CurrentFormCustomizations = _formCustomizationsService.GetByUserId(CurrentUser.ID).ToList();
    }

    public virtual void InitialFormCustomization( Guid formId)
    {
        RemoveFormCustomization(formId);

        var newformCustomization = _formCustomizationsService.GetUserFormCustomization(CurrentUser.ID, formId);
        CurrentFormCustomizations.Add(newformCustomization);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveFormCustomization(Guid formId)
    {
        CurrentFormCustomizations = CurrentFormCustomizations.Where(p => p.FormID != formId).ToList();
    }

    public virtual void InitialGridCustomizations()
    {
        CurrentGridCustomizations = _gridCustomizationsService.GetByUserId(CurrentUser.ID).ToList();
    }

    public virtual void InitialGridCustomization(Guid gridId)
    {
        RemoveGridCustomization(gridId);

        var newgridCustomization = _gridCustomizationsService.GetUserGridCustomization(CurrentUser.ID, gridId);
        CurrentGridCustomizations.Add(newgridCustomization);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveGridCustomization(Guid gridId)
    {
        CurrentGridCustomizations = CurrentGridCustomizations.Where(p => p.GridID != gridId).ToList();
    }

    public ViewFormCustomizations GetFormCustomizationsById(Guid formId)
    {
        return CurrentFormCustomizations.SingleOrDefault(q => q.FormID == formId);
    }

    public ViewGridCustomizations GetGridCustomizationsById(Guid gridId)
    {
        return CurrentGridCustomizations.SingleOrDefault(q => q.GridID == gridId);

    }
}
```

and I register this class as a singleInstance with autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof (AuthenticationMethod)).As(typeof (IAuthenticationMethod)).SingleInstance();
```

but when my user or user's info (formCustomization or GridCustomization) change and I want to reload my AuthenticationMethod with new data (for example function `InitialFormCustomization`) when I want to use my single instance in other form with Autofac `Resolve` , old data returns instead of newly updated data...
how can I solve my issue?

---

Answer (score 1):

[Single instance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance) is working exactly how you specified it - it returns a singleton. But your data is for the current user only. This is a problem if all of the users share the same instance of the object.

Generally speaking, services should not have any state associated with them. State is *runtime data* that should normally [pass through the methods of application services](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

But all of that aside, you need to plan another way to store your state than to put it into the DI container. If this is a web application, session state might be one option, or read [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/) for some possible (better) alternatives.